# Trying to use PyCryptodome AES ECB decryption with offsets

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes, pycryptodome

As a bit of context to this I am converting a java file to python and am on the last operation. I'm at about 200 LOC so it makes it that much more edge of the seat...

Anyways, in java the operation is:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ecb/nopadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keys[i], "AES"));

//doFinal(byte[] input, int inputOffset, int inputLen, byte[] output, int outputOffset)
cipher.doFinal(save, saveOffset, 16, save, saveOffset);
```

In python I have this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
cipher = AES.new(bytes(keys[i]), AES.MODE_ECB)
cipher.decrypt(?????)
```

This is taken from the package under decrypt():

```
:Parameters:
  ciphertext : bytes/bytearray/memoryview
    The piece of data to decrypt.
    The length must be multiple of the cipher block length.
:Keywords:
  output : bytearray/memoryview
    The location where the plaintext must be written to.
    If ``None``, the plaintext is returned.
:Return:
  If ``output`` is ``None``, the plaintext is returned as ``bytes``.
  Otherwise, ``None``.
```

As you can see .decrypt() doesn't really have an input for offsets, but I was wondering if there was some way around this?

This is why I decided to post on SO, would I be able to send:

```
temp_bytes = save[offset]
temp_decrypt = cipher.decrypt(temp_bytes)
save[offset] = temp_decrypt
```

Or when decrypting does it use the whole file as context and i will get the wrong output? I would love to just do it and test it but the output is just gibberish that i will have to write another program to parse (another java to python project).

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was:

```
save[saveOffset:saveOffset+16] = cipher.decrypt(save[saveOffset:saveOffset+16])
```

Did not expect it to work so easily